How to delegate android task to GPU
I am new to ondevice ml. I was playing with the Mediapipe official android llm power chat app. I can run the android app however, I was curious whether it is using CPU or GPU.  I could not found a way to do it.
If anyone know how to configure the runtime on GPU or CPU please help.
I thought probably during loading the model I would be able to set the runtime however in the following function
public static LlmInference createFromOptions(Context context, LlmInferenceOptions options) {
        LlmOptionsProto.LlmSessionConfig.Builder sessionConfig = LlmSessionConfig.newBuilder();
        sessionConfig.setModelPath(options.modelPath());
        sessionConfig.setCacheDir(context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
        sessionConfig.setNumDecodeStepsPerSync(3);
        sessionConfig.setMaxTokens(options.maxTokens());
        sessionConfig.setTopk(options.topK());
        sessionConfig.setTemperature(options.temperature());
        sessionConfig.setRandomSeed(options.randomSeed());
        return new LlmInference(context, STATS_TAG, (LlmOptionsProto.LlmSessionConfig)sessionConfig.build(), options.resultListener());
    } 

I did search for other classes such as taskoption which has methods to delegate tasks which is the following.
private void setDelegateOptions(AccelerationProto.Acceleration.Builder accelerationBuilder, BaseOptions.DelegateOptions.GpuOptions options) {
    InferenceCalculatorProto.InferenceCalculatorOptions.Delegate.Gpu.Builder gpuBuilder = Gpu.newBuilder().setUseAdvancedGpuApi(true);
    Optional var10000 = options.cachedKernelPath();
    Objects.requireNonNull(gpuBuilder);
    var10000.ifPresent(gpuBuilder::setCachedKernelPath);
    var10000 = options.serializedModelDir();
    Objects.requireNonNull(gpuBuilder);
    var10000.ifPresent(gpuBuilder::setSerializedModelDir);
    var10000 = options.modelToken();
    Objects.requireNonNull(gpuBuilder);
    var10000.ifPresent(gpuBuilder::setModelToken);
    accelerationBuilder.setGpu((InferenceCalculatorProto.InferenceCalculatorOptions.Delegate.Gpu)gpuBuilder.build());
}

But I could not figure out how to use this function in the Llminference class such that I can set the runtime to GPU
